# Como aumentar o valor do STEP no input Range conforme rolo a barra

Tags: javascript, html

tudo bem com vocês?

Bom, eu tenho um input range parecido com esse abaixo, bem simples que eu uso junto de uma funçãozinha em JS pra imprimir na tela o valor.

```html
<input type="range" name="valor" class="slider" id="inputRange" value="0" min="0" max="1000000" step="1000">
```

```js
var inputRange = document.getElementById("inputRange");
var printValue = document.getElementById("printValue");

printValue.innerHTML = inputRange.value;

inputRange.oninput = function() {
  printValue.innerHTML = parseInt(this.value).toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' });
}

// Disparar o evento manualmente
var event = new CustomEvent("input");
inputRange.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Usei esse valor como exemplo, de 0 à 1 milhão com um step de 1 mil.

Eu gostaria saber se tem alguma forma deu delimitar esse step conforme o valor for aumentando, por exemplo: de 0 à 10 mil o step continue em 1 mil. De 10 mil à 100 mil o step seja 10 mil. De 100 mil à 500 mil o step seja 50 mil. De 500 mil à 1 milhão o step seja 100 mil e por aí vai...

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Mas vc quer altera-lo em quais condições? qual evento vai dispara a alteração desse número, o que vc vai usar como referencia para definir o número?

Comment: Eu penso em já deixar algo predefinido e basicamente quando o value atingir um valor, por exemplo 100 mil, o step passa a ser 10000.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que o que você realmente quer é fazer um slider com valores exponencialmente crescentes, não necessariamente alterar o valor do step do range.
Assim, você pode pegar o valor realmente retornado pelo slider, e convertê-lo, **após** ter sido entrado. Por exemplo, você pode usar algo como (repare nos valores do range):

```
<input type="range" name="valor" class="slider" id="inputRange" value="0" min="0" max="1000" step="1">
```

Seguido pelo seguinte código, que retornaria valores na faixa que você quer:

```
    var inputRange = document.getElementById("inputRange");
    var printValue = document.getElementById("printValue");
        
    printValue.innerHTML = inputRange.value;
        
    inputRange.oninput = function() {
        max = 1000 // deve ser igual ao "max" do "range" acima.
        falta = 3 // (max * 10^falta) será o valor máximo obtido.
        grand = Math.pow(10, Math.round(falta * this.value / max));
        valor = Math.round(this.value * grand);
        printValue.innerHTML = valor.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' });
    }

    
    // Disparar o evento manualmente
    var event = new CustomEvent("input");
    inputRange.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Espero que resolva.